# Fixing a typo in machine name

Tags: sql-server-2008

When i installed windows i had a typo in the machine name that i corrected from the system's 'Computer Name/Domain Changes' - the workstation is a member of a workgroup not a domain. From everything i can see the renamed machine name is correct.

Shift gears.... I'm importing SQL logins from my remote server to this, my development workstation and have used the [script presented here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992) - a script that generates a CREATE statement for each login found. While I was preparing to run this script's output (from the remote box) i needed to change the domain name from the remote to my local's name - so i ran the same script locally (in order to see what SQL things my domain name is.

SQL has the original machine name - the one with the typo. However, the scripts are tossing errors if i try to create logins with that identifier.

```
CREATE LOGIN [Setve\Admin] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master]
```

But works correctly if i use the updated machine name:
    CREATE LOGIN [Steve\Admin] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master]

So the problem is: do i have a problem i need to solve? Somewhere, deep in the guts of SQL Server, it has record of a Domain name that does not exist. Should i find and fix that discrepancy?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check what SQL Server thinks your machine is named, execute the following:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name'
```

If *Server Name* returns the typo'd name, you can change it with:

```
sp_dropserver <old_name>
GO
sp_addserver <new_name>, local
GO
```

This [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx) documents SQL Server renaming quite well.

**Edit:** Per your comment, much like renaming a Windows computer, you will need to restart the SQL Server service for the changes to take effect.

```
REM Stop SQL Server
sc stop mssqlserver

REM Wait a little bit, and/or run
sc query mssqlserver
REM will tell you the status of the service.


REM Start SQL Server
sc start mssqlserver
```

You can also stop/start SQL Server from within SSMS.

Comment: much appreciated - the commands executed without error, but initially, the new name didn't show up until after restarting. suggest editing your reply to include that. again...thx